# Avoid hardcoding the date that I want to search for in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, ssms, datepart

Here is the issue:

> All the employees (full names please!) and the skills that need updating in the next year.  Do not hard code the date in your query.

Below shows the way that I have done it but It has a hard coded date. I want to be able to get next year no matter when I was to run the search.

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, surname) as 'Full Name',skillId, dateLapses  From EmployeeSkill
Full Join Employee ON EmployeeSkill.employeeId = Employee.id
Where Datepart(YYYY, dateLapses) = 2020;
```

Below is the output I get, I want to replicate it without hard coding the date.

```
Judy                Jetson              Forklift    2020-09-11
Donald              Quagley             Forklift    2020-09-11
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, surname) as FullName, skillId, dateLapses
WHERE EmployeeSkill Full Join
     Employee
     ON EmployeeSkill.employeeId = Employee.id
WHERE YEAR(dateLapses) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()));
```

That said, an improved query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.firstName, e.surname) as FullName, skillId, dateLapses
WHERE Employee e JOIN
      EmployeeSkill es
      ON es.employeeId = e.id
WHERE es.dateLapses >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1, 1, 1) AND
      es.dateLapses < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 2, 1, 1);
```

Notes:

- Qualify all columns names, so it is clear where they come from.
- Use meaningful table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.
- `FULL JOIN` is rarely needed and certainly not in this case.  The `WHERE` clause is turning it into a `LEFT JOIN` anyway.
- The date logic is index-friendly (*sargable*), because the arguments to the functions are not coming from table data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.firstName, e.surname) as FullName, es.skillId, es.dateLapses
FROM Employee e JOIN
      EmployeeSkill es
      ON es.employeeId = e.id
WHERE YEAR(es.dateLapses) = YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1
```

Unless you had a lot of data and an index on dateLapses, then I would use below. BETWEEN lets it use an index.

```
 es.dateLapses BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1, 1, 1) AND
       DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 2, 1, 1));
```